# Iterate all files in a directory (including files that start with '.' - hidden files) in linux/android

Tags: android, linux, shell

I want to iterate through all files in a specified directory including hidden files in a script

i tried something like this:

```
for f in /home/pedja/test/*; do
```

Which shows only visible files (files that don't start with `.`)
If i do this:

```
for f in /home/pedja/test/.*; do
```

It shows only hidden files (files that starts with `.`)

How can i list all files in a single for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           IFS=$'\n'; for f in $(ls -a);do echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: how do we do that?set IFS="\n" ? dis way?it was not woring

Comment: Now its working for directory with space as well.Thanks @loreb .

Comment: @pedja can you try now?

Comment: Unfortunately when $(something) produces a glob pattern, it's also expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for f in `find /home/pedja/test -maxdepth 1`; do
```

Comment: I suggest you try out that `find` command, because a depth of zero will not give anything but the current directory (`.`).

Comment: @joachim-pileborg Thanks, corrected! I actually tried with both `-maxdepth 1` and `-maxdepth 0`, but accidentally pasted the wrong one.

Comment: This also lists that directory itself. Although i could probably filter it out, its not an ideal solution. And it also doesn't work if dir has space in name

Comment: @pedja Wont a simple `find /home/pedja/test -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec dostuff {} \;` do for you?

Comment: @jotik you could elaborate more about your solution, so that it can be useful for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

use brace expansion:

```
for f in /home/pedja/test/{,.}*; do echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: Closest to a solution so far, but i get every hidden file/dir twice

Comment: that is because you have enabled dotglob, try disable it first: shopt -u dotglob

Answer (score 0):

This form runs it on a subshell but that's the safest you can have when your shell does not support process substitution.

```
find /home/pedja/test/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' | while read -r file; do
    ...
done
```